# Are there use-ready Ticket Systems for iphone app developers?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ticket-system

I'll release my first app soon, and I'm afraid of getting dozens of bug mails from users every day. Tapbots for example have a great Ticket System in place. When you send them an support inquiry from their web form, you immediately get an email in return with an big ID in the subject, and some professional text like "please always provide this ID in communications with us". I can only imagine how cool this looks on their backend, seeing all those trillions of mails grouped nicely together with nice chevrons for expanding/collapsing, a big inbox showing all undone emails, etc.

So which Ticket System could I use if I am NOT an server admin pro, and if I am NOT a web developer? I actually don't really want to install some PHP stuff on my server. It just appears way too error prone to me, and I just don't trust these things.

I hope there's some kind of service for that. I don't mind to pay something for this. Must not be neccessarily free.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [ZenDesk](http://www.zendesk.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Check out UserVoice.com

Answer (score 1):

Tender is a great service for helping out with support. It will allow you to collect support requests from multiple locations: email, website, etc. Tender will also help you create a support knowledge base so that customers can find solutions to issues themselves (helping to reduce the burden on you). You can even skin it to look like you want if that is important to you.

In my experience it works reasonably well.

http://tenderapp.com/